# When I declare a variable it shows Error 91 when I create a Variable ¿Any Idea of why that happens?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically when I do this on Excel VBA it works great:

`Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(FilaFinalK, "K")).Select`

But when I declare it as a variable and then select it,  it gives me error 91.

```
Dim List As Range 
List = Range(Cells(2, "K"), Cells(FilaFinalK, "K"))
List.Select
```

¿Can any one help me sith this please?

Comment: You need `set List =...`, range is an object, and all objects need to be set.

Comment: jeje that was easy to fix! haha thank you!!

Comment: [Difference between Dim and Set](https://youtu.be/77c3c0Zdsgc)